# Passing one forms data to another forms datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I have a Billing form with a datagridview. This form contains a update last bill button, which opens a new window asking to enter Bill number. I'am fetching values based on bill number and want to display it in another form. How can I pass table values from one form to another forms datagridview?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                    con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM POS WHERE Bill_No=@Billno", con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billno", txt_EnterBillNoPOS.Text);
```

I want to store this result and display it in another forms datagridview.

Comment: Any related code would be most helpful to help you...

Comment: i have updated the code.

Comment: You could basically do this by having a public property in your target form and assign it to you data table from your main/caller form. But without further details, it is hard to point out exactly where you get it wrong.

Comment: Do you read this data into a DataTable?

Comment: yes. My problem is.. I have a form with datagridview. another form with textbox and an update button. i want to get the bill number in the textbox and when i press update i want to fetch values from database based on bill number and display it in another forms datagridview.

Comment: you can set a variable (maybe write a function to pass the variable and show this form with textbox) when you press Update button set the textbox value in the variable and hide the form, and in the grid form you refresh the grid using the value from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question the right way, you want to transport data from you childform back to your Mainform. For this purpose you can use a Property on you childform for example (there are many possible solutions). This would look sth. like this:

```
//Your third Form filled with billdata from second Form.
public class ThirdForm : Form
{       
   public ThirdForm(DataTable billData)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      yourGrid.DataSource = billData;
   }
}

//Your secondform fetch the data and start the thirdform
public class SecondForm : Form
{        
   private void OnUpdateButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                              con.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM POS WHERE Bill_No=@Billno", con);
      da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Billno", txt_EnterBillNoPOS.Text);

       DataTable result = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(result); //Fill your Table with data

       //Here you pass the data via Constructor
       var thirdForm = new ThirdForm(result);
       thirdForm.Show();
    }
}

//The firstform which starts your flow by activating secondform
public class FirstForm : Form
{   
    private void OnUpdateLastButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var childForm = new SecondForm();
       childForm.Show(); //Shows the second form
    }
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: those are just 2 forms.  My problem is.. I have a form with datagridview. another form with textbox and an update button. i want to get the bill number in the textbox and when i press update i want to fetch values from database based on bill number and display it in another forms datagridview.

Comment: @Abhijith By "another forms" you mean a third or furth form?

Comment: there are 3 forms. First form contains point of sale details. in that i added a button to update last billed sale. so i added 2nd form to get bill number. it contains a update button. I have one more, 3rd form which contains the gridview. so when we enter the bill number in 2nd form and press update the details based on bill  number from 2nd form should display in 3rd forms datagridvirew. its my idea. hope u got that.